# I can't import com.itextpdf.text.Document class

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, document

I'm building an android app and I want to use iText for creating pdf file, but I can't use Document class. As I seen in tutorials, there should be import com.itextpdf.text.Document for using Document class. For this app, I'm using com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.9 library. I want to create a simple pdf file with 2 paragraphs, something like this:

```
    try{
        File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "pdfdemo");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdir();
        }

        Date date = new Date() ;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder + timeStamp + ".pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, output);

        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph(mSubjectEditText.getText().toString()));
        document.add(new Paragraph(mBodyEditText.getText().toString()));

        document.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {}
```

'

Could anyone help me with this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an error message somewhere? Does the import fail?

Comment: @J.Dow The class is present in iText: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/Document.java The problem is simple: the OP is using an addon of the library instead of the actual library.

Comment: Well, the code doesn't include project setup and import statements, so i just wanted to make sure everything is in place. There is also http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html ;)

Comment: "As I seen in tutorials" - please give the URL of that tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say:

> I'm using [com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.9](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/develop/pdfa) library

That is wrong for two reasons:

1. [itext-pdfa](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/tree/develop/pdfa) is an addon to iText that is meant for writing or manipulating PDF/A documents. It requires the core iText libary. Read about the different parts of iText on the official web site: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-java
2. You say you want to use iText on Android, but you are referring to iText for Java. iText for Java contains classes that are not allowed on Android (`java.awt.*`, `javax.nio`,...). You should use the Android port for iText, which is called iTextG: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

It's as if you're using iText without having visited the official iText web site. How is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just open your app level gradle file and add following code into your dependencies

implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.9'

It works for me

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about Gradle, why do you assume the OP uses Gradle?